# How to number version for metadata

Tags: version, metadata, versioning

I have made changes to `App_Questions_Base_.json` How do I number a metadata for versioning if I make a change to a metadata file?
Metadata is being versioned and creating an entry in database.

Answer (score 0):

For example of App questions heirarchy , in the file App Questions.json , any change in any file would have maxVersion + 1.

For example if App_Questions_Base_.json is changed and it has 31 as the version and main version ( bottom of the same file) has 33 as the version
the new version for Base and main version will be 34.

Here is the example of before and after

Before change

```
{
    "App Questions": {
        "Base": {
            "version": 31
        },
        "HIT_Term_RARE_Haven": {
            "version": 33
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven": {
            "version": 32
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_NY": {
            "version": 32
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_CA": {
            "version": 29
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_CT": {
            "version": 29
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_FL": {
            "version": 29
        },
        "HIT_Term_ICC_CAS": {
            "version": 31
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_CAS": {
            "version": 29
        },
        "HIT_Term_ICC_MMDirect": {
            "version": 29
        },
        "HIT_Term_NonICC_MMDirect": {
            "version": 29
        },
        "version": 33
    }
}
```

After change

{
    "App Questions": {

> "Base": {
>               "version": 34
>           },

```
    "HIT_Term_RARE_Haven": {
        "version": 33
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven": {
        "version": 32
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_NY": {
        "version": 32
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_CA": {
        "version": 29
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_CT": {
        "version": 29
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_Haven_FL": {
        "version": 29
    },
    "HIT_Term_ICC_CAS": {
        "version": 31
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_CAS": {
        "version": 29
    },
    "HIT_Term_ICC_MMDirect": {
        "version": 29
    },
    "HIT_Term_NonICC_MMDirect": {
        "version": 29
    },
```

> "version": 34

```
}
```

}